.NET upgrade didn't update web.config or app.config framework settings
I have a solution with 6 projects, all of which were running .NET 4.0.  I went into each one and updated them to target .NET 4.8 (Properties-->Application-->Target framework).
After this, when I do a clean and rebuild, I still see remnants of .NET 4.0 in some configs (below).  Should the target framework update process have adjusted those automatically?  Should I update them manually?  Any other manual "gotchas" that I should check?
app.config:
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>

web.config:
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"> 

